# Time a function in erlang

Tags: performance, datetime, erlang

I'm trying to compile the following erlang code:

```
   my_time_func(F) ->
    {Mega, Mini, Micro} = now(),
    F,
    {SMega,SMini,SMicro} = now(),
    {FMega,FMini,FMicro} = {SMega - Mega, SMini - Mini, SMicro - Micro},
    if 
        FMicro < 0 ->  %guard 1
                if 
                    FMini - 1 < 0 -> {FMega - 1, FMini, FMicro + (FMicro * 2) + 1};
                    true > 0 -> {FMega, FMini - 1, FMicro + (FMicro * 2) + 1};
                end;
        true ->  %guard 2
                if 
                    FMini < 0 -> {FMega - 1, FMini + (FMini * 2) + 1, FMicro} ;
                    true > 0 -> {FMega,FMini,FMicro} ;
                end;
    end.
```

However it says that I have a syntax error before end at line 19 (this being the first end). Am I missing some kind of semicolon?

Initially I was going to post this on code review because this code is very "ugly". Is there a better way to do something like this? (timing a function) without using the build-in function and preferably the erlang module alone.

Comment: Another solution is to use functions in the `timer` module, either `timer:tc/1/2/3` to do it all or `timer:now_diff/2` if you just want the time difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the erlang `if` expression

```
if
    GuardSeq1 ->
        Body1;
    ...;
    GuardSeqN ->
        BodyN
end
```

Therefore, you need to remove `;` before the `end` that belongs to `if` expressions, fixed version is as follow;

```
   my_time_func(F) ->
    {Mega, Mini, Micro} = now(),
    F,
    {SMega,SMini,SMicro} = now(),
    {FMega,FMini,FMicro} = {SMega - Mega, SMini - Mini, SMicro - Micro},
    if 
        FMicro < 0 ->  %guard 1
                if 
                    FMini - 1 < 0 -> {FMega - 1, FMini, FMicro + (FMicro * 2) + 1};
                    true > 0 -> {FMega, FMini - 1, FMicro + (FMicro * 2) + 1}
                end;
        true ->  %guard 2
                if 
                    FMini < 0 -> {FMega - 1, FMini + (FMini * 2) + 1, FMicro} ;
                    true > 0 -> {FMega,FMini,FMicro} 
                end
    end.
```

About the second part of the question, take the difference of two `timestamp`s in microsecond could be another way, something like;

```
now_diff({Meg2, Sec2, Mic2}, {Meg1, Sec1, Mic1}) ->
    ((Meg2 * 1000000 + Sec2) * 1000000 + Mic2) - ((Meg1 * 1000000 + Sec1) * 1000000 + Mic1).

my_time_func(F) ->
    T1 = now(),
    F(),
    T2 = now(),
    Diff = now_diff(T2, T1),
    {Diff div 1000000000000, (Diff rem 1000000000000) div 1000000, Diff rem 1000000}.
```